# Solve for $x$: $\frac{x-a+b}{x-a}+\frac{x-b}{x-2b}=\frac{x}{x-b}+\frac{x-a}{x-a-b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$: $\dfrac{x-a+b}{x-a}+\dfrac{x-b}{x-2b}=\dfrac{x}{x-b}+\dfrac{x-a}{x-a-b}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{(x-a)+b}{x-a}+\dfrac{(x-2b)+b}{x-2b}=\dfrac{(x-b)+b}{x-b}+\dfrac{(x-a-b)+b}{x-a-b} \ \ \ ...(1)$

$\Rightarrow 1+\dfrac{b}{x-a}+1+\dfrac{b}{x-2b}=1+\dfrac{b}{x-b}+1+\dfrac{b}{x-a-b} \ \ \ ...(2)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{b}{x-a}+\dfrac{b}{x-2b}=\dfrac{b}{x-b}+\dfrac{b}{x-a-b} \ \ \ ...(3)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{b(x-2b)+b(x-a)}{(x-a)(x-2b)}=\dfrac{b(x-a-b)+b(x-b)}{(x-b)(x-a-b)} \ \ \ ...(4)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{b(2x-2b-a)}{(x-a)(x-2b)}=\dfrac{b(2x-2b-a)}{(x-b)(x-a-b)} \ \ \ ...(5)$

$\Rightarrow b(2x-2b-a)(x-b)(x-a-b)=b(2x-2b-a)(x-a)(x-2b)\ \ \ ...(6)$

$\Rightarrow (x-a)(x-2b)=(x-b)(x-a-b) \ \ \ ...(7)$

$\Rightarrow x^2-2bx-ax+2ab=x^2-ax-bx-bx+ab+b^2 \ \ \ ...(8)$

$\Rightarrow 2ab=ab+b^2 \ \ \ ...(9)$

$\Rightarrow a=b \ \ \ $

So the result I got does not solve for $x$. Clearly something went wrong. I can't see it however because to me everything feels correct computationally. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From (6) to (7) you lost the solution $x=(2b+a)/2.$ And from (8) to (9) you lost $b=0.$ You must present the set of solutions $x$ in the case $b=0$ or $a$, and in the case $b\ne0,a.$ And in each case, exclude the values which would make some of the 4 denominators equal to $0.$

So you need to split in three cases:

- If $b\in\{0,a\},$ every $x$ distinct from $a$ and $2b$ is a solution.
- If $b\notin\{0,a\}$ and $a\notin\{0,2b\},$ the unique solution is $x=b+\frac a2.$
- If $b\ne0$ and $a\in\{0,2b\},$ there is no solution.

Comment: But at (6), both sides had $b(2x-2b-a)$, so I could divide both sides by that and get rid of it. You mean I shouldn't do that and instead multiply everything out at (6)?

Comment: I mean $AB=AC$ is not equivalent to $B=C$ but to: $B=C$ or $A=0.$

Comment: So you are saying $b(2x-2b-a)(x-b)(x-a-b)=b(2x-2b-a)(x-a)(x-2b)=0$? But where did you get the information that tells you the equation is equivalent to zero? Thanks.

Comment: I am not talking about $AB=AC=0.$ I am not adding an "$=0$" at the end. I am only saying that $AB=AC\iff A(B-C)=0\iff A=0$ or $B-C=0.$

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson  " so I could divide both sides by that and get rid of it." Yes, you could divide both sides by some quantity **as long that quantity is not $0$**. So you need to split in two cases: Case 1: $b(2x-2b-a) \ne 0$. Case 2: $b(2x-2b-a) = 0$. The first case leads to no solution, the second case to $x = (2b+a)/2$.

Comment: @jjagmath The cases are not exactly these (see my updated my answer). Anyway, I think everything was already clear to Ronald since he upvoted and accepted it.